# Jquery Function only half-works in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've gut a simple function in my page for hiding/showing panes when some tabs are clicked. Simplest thing in the world, right?

Works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE it only half works. It will hide all the sopMonthContainers, but fails to find the container with a matching ID and display it.

```
 $('.sopTab').click(function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass("activeTab") === false){
        $(".sopTab").removeClass("activeTab");
        $(this).addClass("activeTab");
        };
    var selectionID = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".sopMonthContainer").css("display", "none");
    $(".sopMonthContainer#the"+selectionID).css("display", "block");
 });
```

I'm hoping it isn't some stupid typo that I've overlooked, but I've been staring at this thing for nearly an hour trying different variations on the theme. I've tried reworking the selector IDs to make sure they're unique (hence the "the" in the selector on the last line), I've tried selecting using only ID, I've tried using different methods to hide/show... same result no matter what.

EDIT: the relevant markup. It's got some coldfusion elements, anything between ##'s is a coldfusion variable.

```
<div class="sopTab" id="sopContainer#DateFormat(pubdate,'mmmm')#" style="">
    #DateFormat(pubdate,"mmmm")#: <span id="sum#DateFormat(pubdate,"mmmm")#">0</span>
</div>

<cfoutput query="GetProductBasicInfo">
    <div class="sopMonthContainer" style="display:none;" 
    id="theSopContainer#DateFormat(pubdate,'mmmm')#">
        [div content goes here]
     </div>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Could you post some markup as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note for example this:

```
<div class="sopTab" id="sopContainerNovember" style="">November: <span id="sumNovember">0</span></div>

<div class="sopMonthContainer" style="display:none;" id="theSopContainerNovember">
```

when you click on sopTab, the selector you build is

```
#thesopContainerNovember
//  ^
```

but the ID of the target is

```
#theSopContainerNovember
//  ^
```

the IDs did not match(it's the uppercase and lowercase `s` )

Comment: nice catch.  I was trying to find the typo.

Comment: This actually fixed it. I was afraid it was something stupid like that... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the last line should be

```
$(".sopMonthContainer #the"+selectionID).css("display", "block");
```

There should be a space here.  But I might be wrong.  It would help if you would post a link to a jsFiddle or working example.

Comment: barring that....if it's really a unique ID, just do `$('#the' + selectionID)` ... no need for the class

Comment: That breaks it in Firefox/Chrome. What I'm trying to do is select the container _with_ id="the"+selectionID, not something inside the container with that ID.

I'll try and get a jsfiddle or something up and running, but it's part of a big jquery/coldfusion page that's hard to pull just one part out of.

Comment: I think his code is probably right. Looks like he's hiding all elements with class `.sopMonthcontainer` - clearing the display so to speak - then selecting a specific one by id which has the same class but also an id. I'd hazard a guess that this is unnecessary though because ids are unique so he should only need to select it by `$("#the"+selectionID)`

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to see the page.

Comment: @theyetiman Correct. I've tried that solution and it also failed in IE.

Comment: Alrighty, I'm just gonna link straight to it. Forgive the spaghetti code on the rest of the page, I inherited a mess.... :(

http://www.audiogo-library.com/library/client/client_pages/standingorder/sopQuery.cfm

Comment: @Artfulshrapnel OK, so the next question is this: are your ids all unique? The fact that you are taking the id of the clicked element and using it to find a different element with the same id by using the `#` selector sets alarm bells ringing. I see you've put "the" in front of it, but still best to make sure they are unique for all elements on the page. I've seen funny results when you don't have unique ids...

Comment: @theyetiman they are all unique, at least for all elements involved in this form. The rest of the page I've inherited and it's a bit of a mess, so I can't speak for that portion of the code.

Comment: Are you sure it's not failing because of the cfform_submit_status is not defined error on line 144 of sopQuery.cfm

Comment: @BrianHoover I'm with you.. @Artfulshrapnel has an HTML comment inside a `<script>` block

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your page. I noticed there's some code that looks like someone has attemped to comment it out but done it incorrectly.

In your sopQuery.cfm file, change the code here:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
  cfform_submit_status["productSelections"]=null;

  function check_TF_productSelections( theForm ){ 
    cfform_isvalid = true;
    cfform_error_message = "";
   cfform_invalid_fields = new Object();

    if ( cfform_isvalid ){
      return true;
    }else{
      alert( cfform_error_message );
      return false;
    }
  }

//-->
</script>
```

To this:

```
<!--
<script language="javascript">

  cfform_submit_status["productSelections"]=null;

  function check_TF_productSelections( theForm ){ 
    cfform_isvalid = true;
    cfform_error_message = "";
   cfform_invalid_fields = new Object();

    if ( cfform_isvalid ){
      return true;
    }else{
      alert( cfform_error_message );
      return false;
    }
  }


</script>
-->
```

OR... If the code is supposed to be uncommented, change it to this, **but note that the error will persist as the variable `cfform_submit_status` is not defined anywhere:**

```
<script language="javascript">

  cfform_submit_status["productSelections"]=null;

  function check_TF_productSelections( theForm ){ 
    cfform_isvalid = true;
    cfform_error_message = "";
   cfform_invalid_fields = new Object();

    if ( cfform_isvalid ){
      return true;
    }else{
      alert( cfform_error_message );
      return false;
    }
  }


</script>
```

Presumably it's supposed to be defined here:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/bluedragon/scripts/cfform.js"></script>`

But I looked and that file is empty.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try and fix that if I can.... it's in a coldfusion template somewhere, just have to find it now.

Comment: I updated my answer to help a bit more as I found an empty linked js file.

Comment: Hm. Do you think I could just define that variable and make the problem go away? I can't really figure out what it's looking for from the code here. And before you ask, I can't just put the file back. It's stored in part of the site I'm locked out of. Yay trade-secret proprietary backend environments.

Comment: I think commenting the whole lot out will probably be most useful if you can't find the rest of the code. you don't know what kind of jiggery pokery was going on behind the scenes. If there's no code to back up the inline stuff, then get rid of the inline stuff by commenting it out.

Comment: It also looks like cfform.js and mask.js are missing.

Comment: @BrianHoover Yeah, this thing is a goddamn mess. Luckily it's only got about 6 months left on this earth. After that it will be purged and replaced with a nice, clean Magento install. I hope they burn and salt the servers afterwards.